# Why Zend Framework has to be configured through include_path

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path

Why do I have to configure an `include_path` when installing Zend Framework instead of just manually including? I've never done this before and can't really see the point, also I've spent some time trying to figure this out with no luck hence why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I add Zend framework to the include path to be able to use `Zend tool`.

If you want  to create a project structure and add controllers or models or even scripts using Zend Tool you will have to have Zend framework added to your include path.

Another reason you may want to ship your project without the library itself so that the end user doesn't update the framework version himself and break your code.

Also if you are working on different project at a time you may want to keep only one version of the framework shared between different projects. This is handy when you need to update your version of the framework without going through all projects every time.

Comment: Another reason to add it to your include path [early](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.includepath) is because any given Zend Framework request may need to load a lot of class files.  If ZF is first in the include path, it will find all those files on the first try without having to search several directories for each file included.  Complex actions that use lots of Zend objects can include upward of 50 ZF files.  If PHP has to look in 3 directories for each file before it finds the right one, you can see a slight performance hit too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set your php include_path to include the ZF library you could just copy the whole ZEND directory into your applications Library directory and continue on. 
But a lot of us are working on more then one project or don't want to have the library in our application so we add it to the php include_path so php and our application can find it.
Now if you are refering to the windows or linux path, those are required to use the ZF cli components ZF.bat and ZF.sh

Answer (score 1):

When modifying the Include Path you can use Zend Framework without knowing the Full-Path of it. You can simply use `require('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php')` and PHP will search in every include path.

For more information have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path